# Is my batch file compatible with all computers?

Tags: batch-file

Will this work on Windows 8 and always work? I've tested it on Windows 7 but I'm not sure... I had a friend test it and he said that it coudn't find the correct path but I checked and the syntax of the commands is the same and I don't know why there'd be a problem. This is assuming %USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players and %USERPROFILE%\Google Drive exists already

```
@echo off
echo Administrative permissions required. Detecting permissions...

net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.
) else (
echo Failure: Current permissions inadequate. Please run as administatior.
pause >nul
exit
)

echo ---------------------------------------------
echo Below enter "S" for simple install type or "A" for avanced install type.
echo (Simple is recommended, only use advanced if you know what your doing!)
echo ---------------------------------------------

set /p option=Enter:
if /i "%option%"=="S" goto simple
if /i "%option%"=="A" goto advanced


echo Your entry did not match available options. Try again.
pause >nul
exit 

:simple
mklink /d "%USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\Terraria" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players"

cd %USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\Terraria\
copy /y NUL marker >nul
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players

if exist marker (
    echo Validation of installation complete. Symbolic link functional.
    del marker
) else (
    echo SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!!!!!!
)

echo ==============
echo You Selected Simple.  & echo.If there are no errors above, your installation should be complete.
echo ==============
pause >nul
exit

:advanced
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\Terraria"
mklink /d "%USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\Terraria\Players" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players"

cd %USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\Terraria\Players 
copy /y NUL marker >nul
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players

if exist marker (
    echo Validation of installation complete. Symbolic link functional.
    del marker >nul
) else (
    echo SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!!!!!!
)

echo ==============
echo You Selected Advanced.  & echo.If there are no errors above, your installation should be complete.
echo ==============
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Is `%USERPROFILE%\Google Drive\Terraria` assumed to exist already?

Comment: Yes, although his error was the path specified cannot be found...

Answer (score 0):

If delivered that all paths exist....

`mklink` command was introduced in Vista so the script won't work on XP/2003.